# Relative position when resizing browser

Tags: css

I'have 3 div blocks and I would like to place them as in the picture.
It works with the following CSS code, but when I resizes my browser, the blocks aren't exactly at the same position (you can see it at the 2 pictures with comments).

Do you have an idea ? Maybe an other position (absolute or other ?).

PS : I use relative position because I use JqueryUI (draggable, resizable) to create blocks and to position them.

Thanks.

Here is the CSS code :

```
#corps {
  background: black;
}

#bloc {
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

#bloc2 {
  width: 40%;
  background: lime;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 2%;
}

#bloc3 {
  width: 45%;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

[image: Full size page]

[image: Small window]

[image: Small window]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the relative positioning. It's going to cause the elements to be positioned relative to the parent container #corps. If you don't plan on editing that with jQuery in any other way, it's not going to behave like you're describing you'd like it to.

Here's a jsfiddle that iterates the best way to accomplish what you're looking for with css using inline-block display and vertical alignment: https://jsfiddle.net/4gw22vrh/

```
#corps {
  background: black;
}

#bloc {
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}

#bloc2 {
  width: 40%;
  background: lime;

}

#bloc3 {
  width: 45%;
  background: purple;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your response. The problem is that I don't know the order of the blocks etc. because the user can add blocks with JqueryUI and position them where he wants :s

Comment: Oh. Well if I understand correctly, you're going to want all of those boxes absolutely positioned then, and give the parent container that holds them a position property of relative (so all of your boxes are absolutely positioned relative to the larger parent container).

Then, you should be able to edit the absolute containers (boxes) coordinates with your jQuery UI.